# Asus ZE551KL Wifi Battery Drain when turned on but barely using it

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, battery, battery-life

I recenty bought an Asus Zenfone 2 Laser (ZE551KL) with Marshmallow. Battery wasn't good from the start but it got worse and worse, mainly because Wi-Fi uses up to 2/3 of a full charge. I don't watch videos, I don't download content, I only read or play games about 1 hour day. Most of the drain happen mostly when the phone is on standby even if wi-fi is disabled in sleep.

- Notify when public network is available is OFF
- Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep set to NEVER
- Improve location with Wi-Fi scanning is OFF

The only thing that works is disabling the Wi-Fi.

[image]

How can I prevent so much battery use by Wi-Fi?

Comment: Try these : Location → Scanning → WiFi Scanning - disabled ;
Location → Mode → Battery Saving

Comment: Location is always turned OFF and set to GPS only which won't use wi-fi. Wi-Fi scanning is already OFF.

Comment: Use another app like Gsam battery monitor to verify if the WiFi usage is actually high. My device Moto X Play was reported to have the same problem, whereas the actual consumption was not high. Just to eliminate that possibility